# Javascript mouseover alert on div not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onmouseover

Trying to get an alert to appear on mouseover, using Javascript, for a div element. I can get the div element to print in the console, but nothing else happens.

The div has some text in it, I tried changing it to activate on the text instead of the div but I still couldn't get it to work.

```
   window.onload = pageReady;
    function pageReady(){
            
        var buttonBox = document.getElementById("buttonBox");
        console.log(buttonBox);
        
        function askUser(){
            alert("It worked!");}
    
        buttonBox.onmouseover = askUser;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me? Show us your code if this sample isn't enough.

```js
   window.onload = pageReady;
    function pageReady(){
            
        var buttonBox = document.getElementById("buttonBox");
        console.log(buttonBox);
        
        function askUser(){
            alert("It worked!");
        }
    
        buttonBox.onmouseover = askUser;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="buttonBox" height="100px" width="100px" style="background-color: red;">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works for me should be close voted as *Not reproducible or was caused by a typo*

Comment: Do I delete? I think showing a fully working example is helpful to the asker.